# belongsTo and hasMany with inline data

Tags: sencha-touch

Is it possible to use the Ext.data.Model associations belongsTo and hasMany with without explicitly using a Ext.data.Proxy? I have Stores that use the inline data attribute to create Model objects. Should associations work with this type of setup?

Thanks in advance!